# Converting C++ function to C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, algorithm, bitboard

I'm trying to convert c++ funtion to c#, but I'm failing for the second straight hour. Need help:/ The function is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261332/7727517) question

```
bool haswon(unsigned __int64 newboard)
{
    unsigned __int64 y = newboard & (newboard >> 6);
    if (y & (y >> 2 * 6)) // check \ diagonal
        return true;
    y = newboard & (newboard >> 7);
    if (y & (y >> 2 * 7)) // check horizontal -
        return true;
    y = newboard & (newboard >> 8);
    if (y & (y >> 2 * 8)) // check / diagonal
        return true;
    y = newboard & (newboard >> 1);
    if (y & (y >> 2))     // check vertical |
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Here's my c# one:

```
    bool HasWon(ulong newboard)
    {
        ulong y = newboard & (newboard >> 6);
        if ((y & (y >> 2 * 6)) > 0) // check \ diagonal
            return true;
        y = newboard & (newboard >> 7);
        if ((y & (y >> 2 * 7)) > 0) // check horizontal -
            return true;
        y = newboard & (newboard >> 8);
        if ((y & (y >> 2 * 7)) > 0) // check / diagonal
            return true;
        y = newboard & (newboard >> 1);
        if ((y & (y >> 2 * 7)) > 0)    // check vertical |
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

But It doesn't work! Looks like a trivial thing, but I'm totally lost. Thanks for help

Comment: Compare your code with the C code, you should see your copy'n'paste error(s). (Hint: The number of the deadly sins...)

Comment: How is it not working? (what was your input, what was your expected output, which line is not returning what you expect)?

Comment: @RufusL this is an algorithm to check if "Connect 4" game's board is connected (if there are 4 bits in the row). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261332/optimization-chance-for-following-bit-operations) it is explained in details. Basically if you pass "15" you should get true. Because last 4 bits of "15" are "1111". But I can't get it :/ I don't see any "deadly sins" :(

Comment: Yep, I understand. When you step through the code, are all the lines not working? or just some of them? (in your last two lines, you are not shifting `y` by twice the amount that you're shifting `newboard `)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a simple copy/paste error. Your last two lines were not shifting `y` by twice the amount of `newboard`:

```
private static bool isWon(ulong board)
{
    // Check / diagonal
    ulong y = board & (board >> 8);
    if ((y & (y >> 2 * 8)) > 0) return true;

    // Check - horizontal
    y = board & (board >> 7);
    if ((y & (y >> 2 * 7)) > 0) return true;

    // Check \ diagonal
    y = board & (board >> 6);
    if ((y & (y >> 2 * 6)) > 0) return true;

    // Check | vertical
    y = board & (board >> 1);
    if ((y & (y >> 2)) > 0) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: OMG! Now I see it. I broke the algorithm while I was trying to fix it :/ thanks guys. Now I can see why were a little bit confused.

Comment: You also make copy error and reverse order of operations ;)

Comment: Yeah, I rearranged the order, but the checks are all still the same.

Comment: @RufusL wait, why did you rearrange the order? Does it matter?

Comment: @RufusL I see now order is not important

Comment: No, just my brain wanted them to be in descending order